# how do I capture image from running video in android ?

Tags: android, image, video, capture, recording

I have a code that records video from camera. I want to use the camera in 2 ways 1. for video recording 2. image capture & transfer to remote android phone. I can  not use 1 camera for 2 purposes so I have decided to use camera picture callback functions during video recording but that is not working.

Is there any way to get image frames from running video ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SurfaceView or SurfaceTexture you can use preview callback instead of the picture callback. It will take you to onPreviewFrame where you can access the individual frames. look at:

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html